# Puppeteer work fines on local but not after deployment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, puppeteer, cheerio

I have this browser started like this :

```
async function startBrowser() {


const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--no-zygote',
      '--single-process',
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  return { browser, page };
}
```

and I have a function that is called that runs this code :

```
    const { browser, page } = await startBrowser();
  const tab = await browser.newPage()
  const request = await (await tab.goto(``));
  await page.goto(``);
  console.log('scraping...');
  console.log(page.url());
  await page.screenshot({
    path: `frontend/public/assets/${coinId}.png`,
  });
  const text = await request.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(text);
  const coinImage = $('#one img').attr('src');
  const coinTitle = $('#three div h1').text();
  const bids = $('#bidsrow td input').attr('value');
  const timeLeft = $('#endsrow #endstext').text();
  const currentBid = $('#currentbidtext').text();
  const itemId = $('#itemidrow td .bolder').text();
  const minBid = $('#minimumbidtext').text().replace('$', '');
```

On my local machine, it scrapes the data perfectly fine, however when I deploy this app to Heroku or even AWS EC2, it doesnt seem to scrape anything? and just returns empty data.

Is this because the browser is not started correctly? or ?
Spend all day deploying this app to both heroku and aws and still very confused what is wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to scrape? Lots of sites won't serve content when they're being browsed from IP addresses known to belong to cloud providers.

Answer (score 0):

***few changes in browser launch***

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args:[
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--single-process",
    "--no-zygote",
  ],
  executablePath:process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 
    process.env.PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH
    : puppeteer.executablePath(),
});
```

**Add Dockerfile in home directory**

```bash
FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:22.4.1

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable


WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci 

COPY . .

CMD ["node","app.js"] /* app.js replace with ur start node */
```

**Note:** don't forget to add env variable to add render's environment.